# How to solve "setupWithViewPager" issue (Android,Java)?

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-studio

I cannot insert `setupWithViewPager` method for binding "`binding.tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(binding.viewPager);`" I tried many ways but I can not solve this error yet, and I used "Tablayout" and "Viewpager" (Not viewpage 2) in xml file

**activity_main.xml**

```
`<com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:background="@color/cn_colorPrimary"
        android:elevation="12dp"
        app:tabIndicator="@color/white"
        app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/white"
        app:tabMaxWidth="0dp"
        app:tabGravity="fill"
        app:tabMode="fixed"
        app:tabTextColor="@color/white"
        android:id="@+id/tabLayout"/>

    <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/viewPager"/>`


**MainActivity.java**
`protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
        setContentView(binding.getRoot());

        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        binding.viewPager.setAdapter(new FragmentsAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()));
        binding.tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(binding.viewPager);

        getSupportActionBar().hide();
    }`



**import section in MainActivity.java**
`import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Toast;


import com.connect.connectproject.Adapter.FragmentsAdapter;
import com.connect.connectproject.databinding.ActivityMainBinding;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;`
```

[The error section of that java file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4yCJI.png)
so please guide me to solve this error..

I need an alternative or solution for my issue to solve my problem.

Comment: Typo. You have the wrong tag in the layout XML. You want `<…TabLayout>`, not `<…TabItem>`. You might need to clean/rebuild the project after making changes.

Comment: Did Mike's comment help?

Comment: yeh, it's really help to me, Thanks for your help @AlexMamo